# Implementing a sticky toolbar as in google inbox with angular material

Tags: material-design, angular-material

In inbox, there is a toolbar at the top that is persistent, but there is also a toolbar on each card representing a conversation. If you scroll down far enough that that toolbar should be hidden under the one at the top of the screen, it instead anchors itself below the main toolbar and the rest of the card moves beneath it. Is it possible to implement this functionality in angular material?